# Global constant initialised with a return value

Tags: vb6

Please see the code below from Globals.bas:

```
Public Const Day = "Tuesday"
```

I have declared a constant called Day and Day is available throughout the project, so I can do this anywhere and I will be prompted: Tuesday:

```
msgbox(Day)
```

Is it possible to do this in the Globals.bas:

```
Public Const Day = getDay
```

Where getDay is a function that returns the day?

In VB.NET you have application scope.  I am wandering if there is something similar when using VB6.

Comment: a Constant, by definition, needs to be known at compile time, so it cannot be the result of a function determined at runtime

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign a function to a global constant.  You can make a global function though.

```
Public Function GetDay() As String
  GetDay = "Tuesday"
End Function
```

Then just call it like this:

```
day = GetDay()
```